# Map function in javascript with splice

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain me how does this function return `[0,1]` when we pass `2,0,1`

```
function processData(input) {
   var parse_fun = function (s) { return parseInt(s, 10); };    
   var lines = input.split('\n');
    console.log(lines)
   var T = parse_fun(lines.shift());
    console.log(T)
    var data = lines.splice(0, T).map(parse_fun);
    console.log(data);    
}
```

The part which is confusing this line.

```
var data = lines.splice(0, T).map(parse_fun);
console.log(data);
```

`lines.splice(0,T)` returns me `[]` then how come `[].map(parse_fun)` return `[0,1]`

Comment: What is an example of `input`? Not sure why it is using `shift`, and `splice` , seems rather confusing to mix mutating methods with with `map` which returns a new array.

Comment: [2,0,1] is the input passed...

Comment: @UnderTaker `[].split; // undefined`, passing `[2, 0, 1]` will throw an error on the line starting `var lines = ...`

Comment: Its not an array, its a comma sep arguement.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming input of `"2\n0\n1"`

Consider what `lines.shift()` does,

- It removes the first item from `lines` and reduces all other indicies by `1`
- It returns the first item that is now removed `lines`

So, in your case, `2` is returned and `lines` becomes `["0", "1"]`

Next, consider what `lines.splice(0, 2)` does

- It removes `2` items from `lines`, starting from index `0`
- It returns an array of the removed items

So, in your case, `["0", "1"]` is returned and `lines` becomes `[]`

Finally, you're mapping the array `["0", "1"]` to numbers base `10` and you get your result `[0, 1]`

Answer (score 1):

> `lines.splice(0,T)` returns me `[]`

No, it doesn't. It will yield `["0", "1"]`. But [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) will also remove those items from the `lines` array, which means that if you call it twice (e.g. once to map over, and once for debugging) the second attempt will return the empty array. You should consider using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead.